# how to remove all zero width space from the text?

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex, text-editors, find-and-replace

I know how to use regular expressions to do the mass search and replace task in editing program
But I don't have or can't find the entire list of zero width space unicode. I quick searched the google and found U+200B to be ZWS but there's many others for sure.
I tried to find online tools for the job with no success. They offer word count, remove all whitespace, or document comparison tools but not ZWS detetor or remover.

these characters are not considered whitespace even though it seems to be. they are special characters like %,* or # but are just invisible.

any help?

Comment: You appear to have created a new account in order to post a non- answer. If you wish to regain control of your question you should register a full account and then use the [contact us](https://superuser.com/contact) form "I need to merge accounts" option which will allow you to request your old profile here is merged into your new one. Then you will be able to edit your question, comment on it and reply to users who have responded.

Comment: I don't have 10 points so I can't answer this question. Currently there is only 1 value:  U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE. To match use one of these regexs: `\x{200b}` or generally `\p{Line_Break=ZWSpace}` for future possible additions

Comment: indeed, ZWSP is the same as \x{200B}. And can be deleted by regex, find and replace in notepad++

Answer (score 1):

To search by Unicode codepoints using UTF-16 you'd use e.g. `\x{200B}`. It works whether the file is encoded with UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Of course you can also use other tabs e.g. **Replace with** NOTHING.

Or you can also use the advanced function **Find in Files** for multiple (filtered) files also in sub-folders.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to match all* zero-width whitespace characters, you should match ["Format" category](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Cf) of Unicode.

```
\p{Cf}
```

See test: https://regex101.com/r/AS2wLz/1

* By "all" I mean, all listed in table "Related Unicode characters with property White_Space=no" at [Wikipedia article "Whitespace character"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) and other included in category `Cf`.

Answer (score 0):

**In python, this is what you can use to delete ZWSP :**

`(r"\u200b", "", re.MULTILINE),`

**See the code below, THERE ARE ALSO other replacements**

```
# Directory-ul în care vrei să aplici căutarea și înlocuirea cu regex
directory = "c:\\Folder-Oana\\extracted\\translated"

# Lista cu regex-urile și înlocuirile corespunzătoare
regex_and_replace = [
    (r"\\\\.*$", "", 0),
    (r"\\.*\\$", "", 0),
    (r"\\.*$", "", 0),
    (r"\\\\.*$", "", re.MULTILINE),
    (r"\\.*\\$", "", re.MULTILINE),
    (r"\\.*$", "", re.MULTILINE),
    (r"\u200b", "", re.MULTILINE),
    (r'<p><link rel="canonical"', '<link rel="canonical"', 0),
    (r'<p><p class=', '<p class=', 0),
    (r"<p></p>", "", 0),
    # Adaugă alte regex-uri și înlocuiri aici
]

# Parcurge toate fișierele din director
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)

    # Verifică dacă este un fișier și obține conținutul
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file_content = file.read()  # Define 'file_content' for each file

            # Aplică fiecare regex și înlocuire în listă
            for regex, replace, flags in regex_and_replace:
                file_content = re.sub(regex, replace, file_content, flags=flags)

            # Scrie conținutul actualizat înapoi în fișier
            with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
                file.write(file_content)

        print(f"Procesat fișierul: {filename}")

# Call the function to delete duplicate files
delete_duplicate_files(directory)
```